# IOFramebuffer can't access VRAM framebuffer in macOS 10.13

Tags: driver, kernel-extension, macos-high-sierra

I am working on a extend graphic driver for MacOS, and use IOFrameBuffer class to publish a linear frame buffer device. In my driver we use getVRAMRange() to return the video ram address information for the entire memory window of frame buffer device.

The question is: The driver can works well on MacOS 10.12, but once upgrading system to MacOS 10.13 High Sierra, I can't access video ram data any more. Do you have any tips on this issue? Thanks very much!

besides, I am also confused why the driver can works well with safe mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old issue, Apple deprecated IOFramebuffer class. we can access screen steam buffer through IOSurfaceRef, and use IOSurfaceGetBaseAddress function get screen data address.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was introduced with the Metal compositor in macOS 10.13. I reported it to Apple early during the beta cycle, but I haven't had any response so far, and it's certainly not been fixed.

The contents of the display does get drawn somewhere in WindowServer, you can access it by taking a screenshot (in userspace) with `CGDisplayCreateImage()`. Depending on what you're trying to do that might work for you?

The reason why the problem doesn't exist in safe mode is that hardware-accelerated compositing (Quartz Extreme) is disabled in safe mode, so the Metal compositor is not used. The problem also doesn't occur on older Macs which don't support Metal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I also think it was influenced by metal. I have tried to use CGDislplayCreateImage() function in user space, but the performance is too poor to meet our requirements.
 
As I know, the newest driver of DisplayLink(http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1033) can works well on MacOS 10.13, so I think, definitely, there is a way to access the video ram data. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: As far as I am aware, `CGDislplayCreateImage()` is the only method that works at the moment. It's definitely possible to achieve realtime performance with it, although it certainly adds an extra framebuffer copy. Do file a bug (radar) with Apple to encourage them to fix it.